# PHP: MySQL values call based on dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli, drop-down-menu, call, mysql-workbench

So what Ia m trying to do is to call a value from my server and input it in a variable based on what I have chosen from the dropdown box and then I want to take those variables and calculate a new output through javascript (I don't think that I want help for the last part but I like being up-front). Anyway, here is the code

```
$db_name = 'prod_chrotex_db';
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id ");

echo '<select name="TITLE">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['title']  . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo 'ID: ' . $rows['ID'] ;
    $value = $rows['values']
};

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You need ajax to do it

Comment: So I can't call a single value through php?Great!

Comment: Wait a second, I am not familiar with AJAX, why can't I do it?I mean I just want some values from MySQL

Comment: You need to handle possible errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$db_name = 'prod_chrotex_db';
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id ");

echo '<select name="TITLE"  id="selectb" onchange="callfunction();>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $rows['ID'] . '" ">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';


};

echo "</select>";

?>
<script>

    function callfunction(){
        var val = document.getElementById('selectb').value();
        // You get the selected value in val variable. Here you can calculate what you want

        }

</script>
```

Comment: So document.getElementById takes the values from a another part of the code, where the function is being called, no?